# How use razor templates in business logic?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need generate email by template base's on razor engine.

Business logic is class library Project. I added System.Web.Razor and RazorEngine.

And created simple cshtml file, but this file don't work like simple razor cshtml. 
Do not have `@model BlablaViewModel` but work `@foreach, @for, @if`

How to user razor power in class library project ?

**UPDATE** it is not duplicated. I need use razor with viewModel but their solutions do not help me.

Comment: this is not helped to me.

Answer (score 0):

ActionMailer might be able to do this for you. It's capable of using Razor templates to generate emails but I don't know how easy it is to get it to work inside a class library project.

https://bitbucket.org/swaj/actionmailer.net/wiki/Home

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to check out [ServiceStack.Razor](http://razor.servicestack.net/).  I have successfully implemented razor websites, in DLLs, using pages as embedded resources.  This allowed me to have a "Common" DLL that had layouts, CSS, javascript, etc, and other DLLs that provided the actual implementation.  Said "common" dll is easily deployable and shareable amongst multiple web applications.